# Why does Git sometimes list conflicts with 'ours/theirs' instead of 'HEAD/branch'?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-merge-conflict

I undid an attempted merge conflict using `git checkout -m <<filename>>` and was surprised to see the conflicts listed as:

```
<<<<<<< ours
-------
>>>>>>> theirs
```

instead of:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
-------
>>>>>>> branch
```

Is there a global setting that controls this?

Comment: This indicates that Git sees the merge as two branches coming together on a third branch, but it doesn't know which takes precedence. You can do a manual fix or use `git checkout --ours`, for example.